# Маленького осетра, с испятнанной мазутом зубчáтой спиной. Обязательна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

У Лопатина:

"§ 53. Несогласованные определения, выраженные существительными в форме косвенных падежей с предлогами и относящиеся к нарицательным именам существительным, обособляются:

1) если определяемое слово уже имеет впереди стоящие согласованные определения:

> В альбоме был большой фотографический снимок: внутренность какой-то пустой часовни, со сводами, с блестящими стенами из гладкого камня (Бун.)".

В Тотальном диктанте 2016 года, наряду с эталонным вариантом расстановки знаков препинанания, в предложении:

"Когда с левого берега Камы, на котором лежит моя родная Пермь, смотришь на правый с его синеющими до горизонта лесами, чувствуешь зыбкость границы между цивилизацией и первозданной лесной стихией..."

допустимым считается поставить запятую перед "с", чтобы обособить несогласованное определение — "с его синеющими до горизонта лесами".

Там же как эталонный приводится такой вариант:

"Мальчиком я видел на песке: вся Кама была тогда в мазуте от буксиров".

Возможно ли здесь поставить запятую перед "с" по вышеприведенному правилу Лопатина?

В отличие от первого предложения в диктанте, во втором такой вариант не рассматривается.

Comment: Упс, сайт не засчитал выделение „звёздочками” в первой цитате. Замените, пожалуйста, кавычками. Да и кавычки мне следовало использовать Ваши...

Comment: Артём, премного Вам благодарен 

Comment: @doom1 А где, собственно, маленький испятнанный осетр?

Answer (score 1):

Ага, нашелся.

**Мальчиком я видел на песке маленького осетра с испятнанной мазутом зубчатой спиной: вся Кама была тогда в мазуте от буксиров.** [нейтральная интонация, без акцентов на чем-либо]

Я бы не стала ставить перед "с" запятую (при обычном прочтении).
Если уж выделять, то логическим подчеркиванием с помощью тире, возможно, даже в двух. Почему зубчатая спина испятнана? Потому что в Каме мазут от буксиров. Пунктуация во многом зависит от того, **как** был прочитан текст. Можно, думаю, и вставную конструкцию использовать.

Мне видятся такие "пунктуационные возможности".

Мальчиком я видел на песке маленького осетра — с испятнанной мазутом зубчатой спиной: вся Кама была тогда в мазуте — от буксиров.
Мальчиком я видел на песке маленького осетра [—] с испятнанной мазутом зубчатой спиной (вся Кама была тогда в мазуте [—] от буксиров).

Answer (score 1):

*Мальчиком я видел на песке **маленького осетра с испятнанной мазутом зубчатой спиной:** вся Кама была тогда в мазуте от буксиров.*

**Запятая однозначно не нужна.**

Обособление несогласованных определений делается по следующему **общему** принципу: определение обособляется, если обозначает **уточняющий** признак, и не обособляется, если признак является **отличительным** (основным, определяющим).

**Эта задача для каждого примера имеет свое собственное решение**. Те примеры, которые приводятся в правилах, тоже решены по этому принципу. Подыскать подходящее правило сложно, поэтому лучше исходить из семантики вашего варианта.

В данном случае речь идет об осетре с **вполне определенными признаками,** которые задаются двумя определениями (согласованным и несогласованным). Второе определение является важным, так как  оно связано с уже известной персонажу темой — загрязнением реки мазутом, поэтому оно обозначает **отличительный признак и не обособляется.**

Пример с обособлением: ***Я увидел на песке осетра, маленького, с испятнанной мазутом зубчатой спиной.***  Оглядевшись вокруг, увидел, что весь берег был в мазуте.

Здесь другая ситуация. Персонаж сначала видит рыбу на песке, затем уточняет ее вид и внешние признаки. И только потом ему становится ясной причина.